# Why does this basic java code yield different outputs?

Tags: java

^The question that my question is marked a duplicate of is not the same as this one.
That question is how to get a float from dividing by an integer.

This is my code:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("33/5 is " + 33/5);
    System.out.println("33/5.0 is " + 33/5.0);
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
33/5 is 6
33/5.0 is 6.6
```

Btw if this is a duplicate, please direct me to where this is answered because I was not able to find one.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking - perhaps you should edit in the problem that you're having?

Comment: I asked in the title why the code yields two different outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first calculation `33 / 5` you are actually dividing an integer thus giving you result with no decimal places.

And the second calculation: `33/5.0` the result is actually promoted to **double** which has greater precision than int and resulted to decimal.

Remember that `5.0` is a `double` thus promoting the result of the calculation to double primitive

Answer (score 1):

`int/int`(33/5) will always give `int` so 33/5=6

`int/double`(33/5.0) will give `double` so 33/5.0=6.6